# Polylang language switcher as a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I am using Polylang and I want to put the language switcher next to logotype and cart icon on mobile header. Polylang gives the php code that I can add to the template, but I want to add it as a shortcode. Is there any way to put the language switcher as a shortcode, without adding it as php code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nicomollet/47ba9808f3187c9f1568d8f7c4355b54 Check the code in this gist.

Comment: @VijayHardaha thank's - it works, but it doesn't display flags, only language names despite i changed args.